# How do I specify that a deb package should replace one with a different name?

Tags: debian, configuration, package-management

I am creating a Debian package `foo` which needs to replace an existing package `bar` on systems on which it is installed.

I've read:

https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html

And concluded that the correct clauses in the `DEBIAN/control` should look like:

```
Provides: foo
Conflicts: bar
Replaces: bar
```

However, when I try to install the `foo` package on a system that already has `bar` installed, the system balks because `foo` conflicts with `bar`.

If I remove the `Conflicts: bar` entry then `dpkg` allows both packages to be installed side-by-side, which is a problem since `foo` must replace `bar`.

What are the proper `control` file clauses to achieve this?

I've tried `Breaks` instead of `Conflicts`:

```
dpkg: regarding foo_DEV-22._i386.deb containing foo:
 foo breaks bar
  bar (version 3.2.2.1-x86NX4.4-x86) is present and installed.
  bar provides bar and is present and installed.
dpkg: error processing foo_DEV-22._i386.deb (--install):
 installing foo would break existing software
Errors were encountered while processing:
 foo_DEV-22._i386.deb
```

Comment: Possibly instead of `Conflicts` you should use `Breaks`

Comment: I tried 'Replaces', and that seems to fix the broken pipe error on its own that'd be caused by two packages installing the same file, as long as the one to replace the other is the later version, otherwise, the package with the latest version will be the one that controls the files installed.

Answer (score 3):

`dpkg` is a low level tool. To get the desired effect the package should be put into a repo and added to `sources.list(5)` then `apt install foo` will do the right thing.

Comment: You can use apt with deb file directly: apt install ./foo_DEV-22._i386.deb - mabye it works too.

Answer (score 1):

Why not to rename it the existent package beforehand and later replace it with the one you want?

To this end you have to methods/ways as per Debian official wiki page below:

```
https://wiki.debian.org/Renaming_a_Package
```

Comment: Well, method 1 (provides/replaces/conflicts) is the one that I have tried, that doesn't work. dpkg just refuses to install foo because it conflicts with bar. I haven't got a clue about what method 2 is asking me to do. If you can explain it more clearly, that would be greatly appreciated.